# TensorFlow "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence"

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am trying to start using TensorFlow (1.4.1, with python 3.5.2) by building a simple sort of online -learning LSTM. I wrote the following code to test at least a 1 shot training (train the network with one single sample).

Here are the parameters:

```
input_size = 4
output_size = 4

rnn_size = 128

t=1
```

and here is the RNN code

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
from tensorflow.python.ops import rnn_cell
from tensorflow.contrib import rnn

import numpy as np

import rnnPar as par

x = tf.placeholder('float', [None, par.input_size])
y = tf.placeholder('float')

def reshapeData(x):
    x = tf.transpose(x,[1,0])
    x = tf.reshape(x,[-1, par.input_size])
    x = tf.split(x, par.t)

    return x

def convertData(xs):
    return np.vstack([np.expand_dims(x, 0) for x in xs])

def neural_network_model(x):
    x = reshapeData(x)

    lstm_layer = rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(par.rnn_size)
    outputs, states = rnn.static_rnn(lstm_layer, x, dtype = tf.float32)

    output_layer = {'weights' : tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([par.rnn_size, par.output_size])),
                    'biases'  : tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([par.output_size]))}


    output = tf.matmul(outputs[-1],output_layer['weights']) + output_layer['biases']

    return output

def train_neural_network(x, train_x, train_y):

    prediction = neural_network_model(x)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean( tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction, labels=y) )
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        train_x = convertData(reshapeData(train_x))

        _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: train_x, y: train_y})
        epoch_loss += c
```

i then try to train the network by running the following script:

```
import exampleRNNTF as rnn

train_x, train_y = [[1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0]] , [2.0,4.0,3.0,2.0]
rnn.train_neural_network(rnn.x, train_x, train_y)
```

However this will result in python giving me this strange erro which I can't seem to resolve (with or without the convertData function, i get this error)

```
tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runRNN.py", line 4, in <module>
    rnn.train_neural_network(rnn.x, train_x, train_y)
  File "/home/daddabarba/Desktop/exampleRNNTF.py", line 51, in train_neural_network
    _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: train_x, y: train_y})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 889, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1089, in _run
    np_val = np.asarray(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_dtype)
  File "/home/daddabarba/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 531, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: You're mixing numpy and tensorflow. `convertData(reshapeData(train_x))` won't work

Comment: I see, but i get the same error even if I only use reshapeData, or if I just reshape train_x

Comment: You're trying to do the same processing for `train_x` (which is numpy array) and `x` (which is a tensor). In fact, I really don't understand your code: is this a classification? Why does `train_y` contain floats? Why doesn't `y` have the batch size?

Comment: @Maxim the data has no meaning, i was just trying to run the LSTM. train_y doesn't have a batch size because it is supposed to be online, so you get a new train_y array at each time-step. 

For your information, this has to be later embedded in an Online Reinforcement Learning Algorithm